# A question from Stein-Shakarchi- Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

A simple exercise in the book (mentioned in title) is the following:

*Let $f\colon \Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic, where $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is open. If real part of $f$ is constant, then so is $f$.*

I know the solution which is based on simple applications of Cauchy-Riemann equations. The small technical problem I am facing is that **is it necessary to assume $\Omega$ connected**?

The connectedness of $\Omega$ is not mentioned in the book. Could anybody clarify my doubt?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is necessary to assume $\Omega$ is connected.  Otherwise, e.g. if $\Omega$ has two connected components you could have $f(z) = 0$ in one component and $i$ in the other.